# amazon EMR hive execution error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a simple hive job using amazon EMR console. Every time I get an error stating "Error missing argument base-path" and the hive job fails. Can any one suggest me how to resolve it.

I have inserted the input file into the s3://bucket/inputs location, the script in s3:// bucket / script, and my hive query is as follows:

```
create external table table_name(        
 string var 1, 
 string var 2....) 
Row format delimited 
fields terminated by '/t' 
location 's3://bucket/outputs' 
load data inpath 's3://bucket/inputs/data.txt' into table table_name )
```

In the amazon EMR job flow I have followed all the instructions provided by the amazon documentation. I am a beginner in this field. Is there any need to pass any argument in the arguments lists section in the hive job creation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us some information about your job?

Comment: I have inserted the input file into the s3://bucket/inputs location, the script in s3:// bucket / script, and my hive query is as follows:             create external table table_name(         string var 1, string var 2....) Row format delimited fields terminated by '/t' location 's3://bucket/outputs' load data inpath 's3://bucket/inputs/data.txt' into table table_name

Comment: In the amazon EMR job flow I have followed all the instructions provided by the amazon documentation. I am a beginner in this field. Is there any need to pass any argument in the arguments lists section in the hive job creation

Comment: ... You'd be best off editing your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-- start
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name (string line)
LOCATION 's3n://bucket/inputs/';
```

or

```
LOCATION 's3n://bucket/*/*';
```

I think it works.

- Apache Pig requires protocol **s3://** , however hive requires **s3n://**. I don't know why.

See this site: [S3 Support in Apache Hadoop](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3), there are three types of s3 file prefix.

- S3A (URI scheme: s3a://) - Hadoop 2.7+
- S3N FileSystem (URI scheme: s3n://)
- S3 Block FileSystem (URI scheme: s3://)

Answer (score 0):

The ASF docs explicitly state that on EMR, you must use s3, not any of the others.  Amazon ship with their own S3 client libraries. If Hive requires S3n, it means something is wrong with its classpath, and it isn't picking up the AWS proprietary client —which is not only confusing, potentially trouble.

For the curious, here is [the history of Hadoop S3 support](https://hortonworks.com/blog/history-apache-hadoops-support-amazon-s3/)